# How to define url for firebase storage with Dropzone.js?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, dropzone.js

I'm trying to figure what's URL of Firebase Storage for dropzone.js URL which it requires before to setup.

My current storage in firebase is:

```
var pictureDir = storage.ref(`public_profile/${user.uid}/photos`);
```

And Dropzone.js options... there is a missing URL I had no idea how to add.

```
dropzoneOptions: {
    url: ``,
    thumbnailWidth: 150,
    maxFilesize: 0.8,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    headers: { "My-Awesome-Header": "header value" }
}
```

If I add this var to this URL but I get:

```
Failed to load gs://project33.appspot.com/public_profile/CWWFGRET4534/logo/product.png: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that Cloud Storage for Firebase doesn't support `dropzone.js`. Dropzone [requires a server-side implementation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#server-side-implementation) (which would live at that URL).

If you want the same client-side behavior, you could probably hack at dropzone to use the Storage `put()` method instead of their built-in form `POST`.

Comment: Probably a JS newbie question: How would you go about hacking at `dropzone.js`? Would I need to alter the source code or is there another way?

Comment: @StephanLV you'd want to edit the upload code (https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/blob/master/dist/dropzone.js#L1791) to upload to Firebase, rather than a POST request to some specified URL. You can fork the repo and play with it in your own repo, before deciding if there's a reasonable way to merge it back in.

Comment: Thanks, that would have been my way. Waiting for confirmation form @enyo that this - a function call instead of a post URL - would be a desired way also  from his perspective.